# What's the difference between HTML::linkAction and URL::action in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know that both HTML::linkAction and URL::action work when I am linking to a controller's methods. I read somewhere that the URL class is the "real" one and HTML::linkAction just sends the data to URL::action.

If that's the case are there caveats to this? And more in general, are the duplicate HTML::methods comparable to URL::methods?

Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty simple, even class names say all: `UrlGenerator` and `HtmlBuilder`. So, yes, `HtmlBuilder` uses `UrlGenerator` when creates html elements like links. Output of those 2 methods you mention serve different purposes: eg. `http://localhost/users` and `<a href="http://localhost/users">http://localhost/users</a>`

Comment: Oh I see! I never even realized that one only spits out the link vs an entire html element. I guess I overlooked it with so much laravel jargon to learn! Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HTML::linkAction` returns a string of HTML code for an anchor tag. Example:

```
echo HTML::linkAction('UsersController@getProfile', 'Profile');

// Outputs: <a href="http://domain.com/users/profile">Profile</a>
```

`URL::action`, on the other hand, only returns the URL itself:

```
echo URL::action('UsersController@getProfile');

// Outputs: http://domain.com/users/profile
```